# Choosing Consecutive Seats by Seatrow

Tags: sql-server, subquery

```
SELECT TOP N seats.*, eventtickets.eticketprice from seats 
INNER JOIN eventtickets ON eventtickets.etickettype = seats.seattype 
WHERE ((Seats.seatType ='BOXSEAT') 
AND seatID not in (select seatID from ticketsales WHERE eventID=6))
ORDER BY convert (int, seats.seatSection), seats.seatrow ASC
```

My query above generates the best available # of N seats, but it will fill up one section and then the rest of that order is put in the next section.  I need it to find a new section that has all N seats available.  IF a seat is in `TicketSales` table it is not available.  If `salecategory` is Null then that means ticket has not been SOLD/BLOCK/HOLD so its Available.

It is obviously limited to 6 seats together, but I do have one section which has over 30 seats in one row.

```
Section 1: 
Row 1: 1-2-3
Row 2: 4-5-6

Section 2:
Row 1: 1-2-3
Row 2: 4-5-6
```

etc.

I am at my wits end.  Been staring at this for 2 days straight and my mind is mush. I am pretty weak at SQL, amazing I got this far above.  I think I have gotten close, but no enchilada.

See pics of the 2 main tables attached.  I just need the `seatprice` from `eventtickets` table so it's not that important.

I thank you for any help you can give me on this.

[image: Ticketsales]

[image: Seats]

Answer (score 5):

If you're happy with what you have already, try starting with a set of the distinct sections, cross joining on that, and then filtering your subquery to only that section. That way, it's like considering each section as if it's its own event.

But... why not consider looking at all the seats and finding blocks where the (N-1)th next one is the actual right number away:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT seats.*, eventtickets.eticketprice,
    LEAD(seats.SeatID,@N-1) OVER (PARTITION BY seats.seatSection ORDER BY seats.SeatID) AS SeatNAway
from seats 
INNER JOIN eventtickets ON eventtickets.etickettype = seats.seattype 
WHERE ((Seats.seatType ='BOXSEAT') 
AND seatID not in (select seatID from ticketsales WHERE eventID=6))
) s
WHERE s.SeatId = s.SeatNAway - (@N-1)
ORDER BY convert (int, s.seatSection), s.seatrow ASC
```

See how you go with this maybe... check that you understand the inner subquery, of course.

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Even though writing T-SQL of such kind is a good mental exercise, I suggest that you move this business logic to server or client side, where you can process it with language that at least has arrays.

For example, you can get all available seats from the databases to your web app and render them, and then highlight consecutive ones. It would be much more convenient either in this case, or if any changes are to be made to the location of seats and sections.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it in a roundabout way.  Thanks for your help and advice. I couldn't figure out the `Seatnaway` so I had to do something else....

```
select TOP 3 seats.*, eventtickets.eticketprice from seats
INNER JOIN eventtickets ON eventtickets.etickettype = seats.seattype 
WHERE seats.seatsection IN (SELECT TOP 1 SEATSECTION FROM seats 
WHERE seattype = 'rbox' AND seatHandicap <> 'HANDICAP'
AND (seatID not in (select seatID from ticketsales WHERE (eventID=6 AND (salecategory = 'SOLD' OR salecategory = 'BLOCK')) OR (eventID=6 AND salecategory = 'HOLD' AND seattimestamp > dateADD(mi, -30, getdate()) ))) 
group by seatsection having count(*) >= 3
ORDER BY convert (int, seatSection)) 
AND (Seats.seatType = 'rbox')
AND (eticketcategory = 'STOCKYARDSRODEO')
AND (seatID not in (select seatID from ticketsales WHERE (eventID=6 AND (salecategory = 'SOLD' OR salecategory = 'BLOCK')) OR (eventID=6 AND salecategory = 'HOLD' AND seattimestamp > dateADD(mi, -30, getdate()) )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to party, but here is the sample for finding n consecutive seat in a row.. I checked later that @Rob Farley already suggested similar approach.. I just made it look cleaner for understanding

first sample dataset -

```
+-------+---------+---+
|Seat_No|   Status|Row|
+-------+---------+---+
|      1|   Booked|  A|
|      2|Available|  A|
|      3|Available|  A|
|      4|Available|  A|
|      5|   Booked|  B|
|      6|Available|  B|
|      7|Available|  B|
|      8|Available|  B|
|      9|Available|  C|
|     10|Available|  C|
|     11|   Booked|  C|
|     12|   Booked|  C|
+-------+---------+---+
```

I didn't have local db instance.. so did it in spark sql .. all syntax will remain same.-

to find n=3 consecutive seats -

```
val n: Int = 3

spark.sql(s"""

      select distinct aSeat,seat_list from
      (
        select 
        a.Seat_No aSeat,
        b.Seat_No bSeat,
        lead(b.Seat_No,${n - 1}) over(partition by a.Seat_No order by b.Seat_No) as n_away,
        collect_list(b.Seat_No) over(partition by a.Seat_No order by b.Seat_No asc rows between current row and ${n - 1} following) as seat_list
        from theater a join theater b on 
        a.Seat_No <= b.Seat_No and
        a.Row = b.Row and 
        b.Status = 'Available'
        where a.Status = 'Available' order by a.Seat_No
      ) p
      where p.aSeat + ${n - 1} = n_away order by aSeat

                """).show
```

Here's the output -

```
+-----+---------+
|aSeat|seat_list|
+-----+---------+
|    2|[2, 3, 4]|
|    6|[6, 7, 8]|
+-----+---------+
```